# Incorrect sort of DB query results in micronaut project

Tags: sorting, jpa, micronaut

I am passing this to the repository function:

```
Pageable.from(offset, limit).order(Sort.Order(orderBy, direction, true))
```

It works just fine if orderBy is the name of a String property. If I try to sort by a number property it will return the results ordered as:

1,
11,
12,
...
19,
2,
20,
21

Any suggestions on how to fix for the number ordering?

Doing the sort on the method name (such as findAllOrderByNameAsc) is not an option because this is a parameter that comes from the API. We need to support ordering by any property.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ignoreCase=true parameter or pass it as false

```
Sort.Order(orderBy, direction, true)
```

you should use ignoreCase only on String fields

Comment: orderBy comes from the API. I dont know at if the caller is going to try to sort by a string or a number property. I cant just remove the the ignoreCase = true, because there isn't a method with that signature.

Comment: does it work with ignoreCase = false? if it does you could find out the type of the field on which the caller wants to order using reflection